# Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : attempt to apply non-function calls

Tags: r

I'm trying to run the following code in R, but I'm getting an error.

I'm not sure what part of the formula is incorrect. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
setwd("C:/Rwork/")
data2020<-("ClassData2020.csv")
secaheight<-data2020$seca_Height_mm
chadheight<-data2020$chad_Height_mm
plot(secaheight, chadheight, abline(0,1))
which(data2020[,5]<1710 & data2020[,6]>1750)
del2020<-which(data2020[,5]<1710 & data2020[,6]>1750)
```

[the error message being shown is as follows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmMcE.png)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe could be `data2020<-("ClassData2020.csv")` which should be: 
 `data2020 <- read.csv("ClassData2020.csv")`